# facebook sharer.php is not showing image from URL

Tags: facebook

I m using http://tabbio.com/BarackObama URL to share on facebook
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Ftabbio.com%2FBarackObama

but this url is not showing me an image of barak obama in facebook sharer.php page

guide me that if anything missing

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to add meta tag og:image with url to image you want to show

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://url.to/image"/>
```

to head

Answer (score 0):

nawaz,

to share url with specific details you have to use OpenGraph tags http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Then, for debugging, use Facebook url linter 
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Good luck!